# Retrieve all the available SCNboxes,SCNNode inside a scene and show,hide them

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have recently started IOS App development and currently working on building Arkit applications.

I have an object, which is of type 'SCNBox' and I also have SCNNodes,which are defined as below:

```
var planeGeometry: SCNBox?
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: self.geometry)
self.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

I would like to know the way,through which I can show or hide these planeNodes,planeGeometries.How do I retrieve all these entities for a particular sceneView?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer according to OP's latest comment.

In the ViewController.swift file, you can use following function.

```
var planesHidden = false
@IBAction func togglePlanes(_ sender: Any) {
  planesHidden = !planesHidden
  for (anchor, plane) in self.dictPlanes{
    plane.isHidden = planesHidden
  }
}
```

Haven't tested this too, but I believe this should do the work

Comment: A bit confusing.Actually,I have downloaded a code from "https://github.com/max6363/measure-using-ARKit-iOS11". Can you please quickly go through this and let me know,how I can hide or show the horizontal planes,which are visible. Basically,in every view,some horizontal planes are loaded.You will understand if you can go through that project once. Thanks.Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Let me just clarify one thing: do you want just remove planes visuals forever, or you want to make them switchable by screen button?

Comment: its like,I have added a UI Button,On Clicking on that button,the plane visuals will be hidden.If user clicks it again, then plane visuals will be shown. Hope I am clear?

Comment: Clear enough. Updated the answer

Comment: but it says, there is no method called "hidden".Instead,it shows there is only a method, isHidden() available :(

Comment: try 'isHidden = planesHidden' then

Comment: perfect! Seems to work really fine. Thanks a ton mate!

Comment: glad to help :)